# ef core many to many relation controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to do a controller for a many-to-many relationship between user and project using Entity Framework Core Database First. I have used scaffolding to create the models from database./
create/Add is working but the rest of CRUD isn't ( Edit, details ). How can i achieve that? what am i doing wrong ?

when I click on the edit or get details this error appear
**the Error:**
This page can’t be found

**userproject tabel creation**

```
CREATE TABLE [user_poject] (
    [user_id] INT , 
    [project_id] INT ,
    [user_roles] nvarchar(225)
    CONSTRAINT [user_project_PK] PRIMARY KEY ([user_id], [project_id]),

    CONSTRAINT fk_userProject_user
     FOREIGN KEY([user_id]) REFERENCES [user]([user_id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,

    CONSTRAINT fk_userProject_project 
     FOREIGN KEY([project_id]) REFERENCES [project]([project_id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

**The Controller:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var userPoject = await _context.UserPojects
                                   .Include(u => u.Project)
                                   .Include(u => u.User)
                                   .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UserId == id);
    if (userPoject == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return View(userPoject);
}

// GET: UserPojects1/Edit/5
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var userPoject = await _context.UserPojects.FindAsync(id);
    if (userPoject == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    ViewData["ProjectId"] = new SelectList(_context.Projects, "ProjectId", "ProjectName", userPoject.ProjectId);
    ViewData["UserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "UserId", "UserName", userPoject.UserId);
    return View(userPoject);
}

// POST: UserPojects1/Edit/5
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("UserId,ProjectId,UserRoles")] UserPoject userPoject)
{
    if (id != userPoject.UserId)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Update(userPoject);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!UserPojectExists(userPoject.UserId))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    ViewData["ProjectId"] = new SelectList(_context.Projects, "ProjectId", "ProjectName", userPoject.ProjectId);
    ViewData["UserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "UserId", "UserName", userPoject.UserId);
    return View(userPoject);
}
```

**UserProject Model:**

```
public partial class UserPoject
{
    [Key]
    [Column("user_id" , Order =1)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column("project_id" , Order =2)]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    [Column("user_roles")]
    [StringLength(225)]
    public string UserRoles { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ProjectId))]
    [InverseProperty("UserPojects")]
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
    [InverseProperty("UserPojects")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

**User Model:**

```
  public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            Tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
            UserPojects = new HashSet<UserPoject>();
            UserSprints = new HashSet<UserSprint>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Column("user_id")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("user_name")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Column("user_email")]
        [StringLength(225)]
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty(nameof(Task.User))]
        public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty(nameof(UserPoject.User))]
        public virtual ICollection<UserPoject> UserPojects { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty(nameof(UserSprint.User))]
        public virtual ICollection<UserSprint> UserSprints { get; set; }
    }
```

**Project Model**

```
 public partial class Project
    {
        public Project()
        {
            Sprints = new HashSet<Sprint>();
            UserPojects = new HashSet<UserPoject>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Column("project_id")]
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        [Column("project_name")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        [Column("Project_description")]
        [StringLength(225)]
        public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty(nameof(Sprint.Project))]
        public virtual ICollection<Sprint> Sprints { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty(nameof(UserPoject.Project))]
        public virtual ICollection<UserPoject> UserPojects { get; set; }
    }
```

**DBContext-Fluent API**

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserPoject>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.ProjectId })
                    .HasName("PK__user_poj__5279AEEECFA4D53D");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Project)
                    .WithMany(p => p.UserPojects)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProjectId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK__user_poje__proje__33D4B598");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                    .WithMany(p => p.UserPojects)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK__user_poje__user___32E0915F");
            });
```

Comment: Please show  your user and project classes too.

Comment: @Sergey I added them

Comment: "create/Add is working but the rest of CRUD isn't" - please be more specific. What is not working? How is it not working? Is there any exception thrown? Any error message during any specific operation?

Comment: @atiyar done now

Comment: HI @ZhiLv no, not solved yet, I just meant I added what atiyar asked for to make the question clear

Comment: Hi @HagerHassan, Ok, I understand. From your description, when you click on the Edit or Details button, it will show the page not found error. Please check the Edit and Detail hyperlink, whether the URL is correct (notice the controller and action name), and check whether you have added the related view pages, you can also set a break point in the Edit and Detail action method and try to debug your code.

Comment: @ZhiLv I will thank you

Comment: @ZhiLv every time i trace the code the id is always Null in edit, details, delete. I added the userproject tabel creation code, could it be the error ?

Comment: Hi @HagerHassan, As we can see in the Edit or Details action method, you are adding the if statement to check if the id is null, if the id is null, it will return NotFound error:  `if (id == null){return NotFound();}`. For the id is null error, please check the link button in the Index page, you should add the `id` parameter like this (change the primary key to yours): `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id=item.PrimaryKey})`.Besides, you could check [this sample](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/data/ef-mvc/intro/samples/cu-final/Views/Courses/Index.cshtml).

Comment: you are a lifesaver. that was the error! thank you put it as an answer if you want and I hope you can add m to m controller and action sample

Comment: Hi @HagerHassan, Glad to hear it did help resolve the problem. And I add it as an answer, hoping it can help other community members quickly fix similar issue.

Comment: @ZhiLv thank you for taking time to write such a detailed answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I click on the edit or get details this error appear the Error:
> This page can’t be found
>
> ```
> public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
> {
>     if (id == null)
>     {
>         return NotFound();
>     }
>
>     var userPoject = await _context.UserPojects
>                                    .Include(u => u.Project)
>                                    .Include(u => u.User)
>                                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UserId == id);
>     if (userPoject == null)
>     {
>         return NotFound();
>     }
>
>     return View(userPoject);
> }
> ```

As we discuss previous, by using the above code, if the id is null, it will return the NotFound page. So, the issue is related to the Edit and Detail hyper link on the Index page. Please refer the following code (in the ActionLink method, add the id parameter using the primary key):

```
@model IEnumerable<netcore5.Models.UserPoject>     
<table class="table">
    <thead>
           @*header*@
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserRoles)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  id=item.UserId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {  id=item.UserId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.UserId  })
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Besides, in the Startup.Configure method, if you are using the default MVC route template, like this:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
```

Then, you could also use the following Anchor Tag Helper to add link with the id parameter:

```
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.UserId">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.UserId">Details</a> |
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.UserId">Delete</a>
        </td>
```

The result like this：

[image]

Reference:

[Anchor Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Tutorial: Implement CRUD Functionality - ASP.NET MVC with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a few things, first you will want to use a "PUT" instead of a "POST" for the updated operation.  The caching policy, will allow redundant entries to be collapsed.  Additionally there are ordering rules for PUT where there aren't for POST.  It should be safe for a client to send POST operations in any order and get the same result.

But for the original problem, you are going to want to tell the conext that you have modified the entity.

From a [Microsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

```csharp
// PUT: api/TodoItems/5
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutTodoItem(long id, TodoItem todoItem)
{
    if (id != todoItem.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    _context.Entry(todoItem).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!TodoItemExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return NoContent();
}
```

If that is still giving you an issue, also remove the explicit Bindings, you have the model class proper decorated with attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I tried both but still not found error